# WPF/VB How to set a threestate checkbox (or nullable boolean) to Nothing(null)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, checkbox, threestate

The title explain all itself. For VB the keyword `Nothing` is the same as `False`.

This code verify if checkbox is a three state checkbox, and set the default value, `indeterminate` if is a "three state", and false if is not.

```
myThreeStateChkbox.IsChecked = If(myThreeStateChkbox.IsThreeState, Nothing, False)
```

**The result is the same, always `False`. How can I set the `indeterminate` state ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `New Nullable(Of Boolean)`?

```
myThreeStateChkbox.IsChecked = If(myThreeStateChkbox.IsThreeState, New Nullable(Of Boolean), False)
```

Or shorter just `New Boolean?`:

```
myThreeStateChkbox.IsChecked = If(myThreeStateChkbox.IsThreeState, New Boolean?, False)
```

Comment: Yes! It works, and at the same time I have found another solution, I write it as an alternative `myThreeStateChkbox.IsChecked = If(myThreeStateChkbox.IsThreeState, DirectCast(Nothing, Boolean?), False)`